# Why won't this query update the field with the lookup?

Tags: sql, nested, lookup

I'm trying to run the following query to update one table from another. The dates and email address work and carry across, but the nested query I'm using to get Subject_1 from a reference table does not. What am I doing wrong?

```
 SELECT
    FirstRegistered As SignUpdate,
    (SELECT Subj_ClusName FROM tblSubjectLookup INNER JOIN PAD_ApplicantLost2000 ON tblSubjectLookup.Subj_Name=PAD_ApplicantLost2000.raw_subj_interest_1) AS Subject_1,
    Email_Address
 FROM PAD_ApplicantLost2000
```

The origin table, PAD_ApplicantLost2000, has a 'raw subject' column which contains, for example, 'Biology'. There is another table, tblSubjectLookup, which has codes for all subjects, so Subj.Name has 'Biology' and 'Subj_ClusName' has 'B1', which is what needs to go in my target table. However, the Subject_1 field in the target table does not populate.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a `WHERE` clause instead of joining the table again. I also added `LIMIT 1` just to make sure only 1 value is returned.

```
SELECT
  FirstRegistered As SignUpdate,
  (SELECT Subj_ClusName FROM tblSubjectLookup WHERE tblSubjectLookup.Subj_Name = PAD_ApplicantLost2000.raw_subj_interest_1 LIMIT 1) AS Subject_1,
  Email_Address
FROM PAD_ApplicantLost2000
```

Another, possibly better, way to do it would just be to join the table directly.

```
SELECT
  FirstRegistered As SignUpdate,
  Subj_ClusName AS Subject_1,
  Email_Address
FROM PAD_ApplicantLost2000
LEFT JOIN tblSubjectLookup ON tblSubjectLookup.Subj_Name = PAD_ApplicantLost2000.raw_subj_interest_1
```